# Share custom url in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, schema

I implement custom Url say `SomeURL://` into my app.
But if I shared this link to some website or email, say Twitter then user will **not able to click on this link** & open my app.

Twitter is show as following

[image]

**How can I achieve this?**

**Help me**

**Thanks**

Comment: use custom URL Schema, follow this tutorial http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: please check with following link..  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, you are  mis-understand my question. I am facing problem with sharing.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik,  you are mis-understand my question. I am facing problem with sharing

Comment: in at present I used custom URL schema in my app, my app name is **OUTT** , in here i follow above two tutorials it well working fine for me

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, what you are doing if you share URL with custom schema on Twitter?

Comment: whatever we want share u can share into your social place where u like in whatsapp, Facebook, message , mail, etc..., the only two things is identify your app, 1. URL Identifier : "your bundle ientifier", 2. URL schema :"your app name".  if both are valid it automatically redirect to your app , the **openhandleURL** method handle the after the things, example https://dev.twitter.com/cards/mobile/url-schemes

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, thanks for answer. let me check

Comment: ya sure if need assistance inform me I surely assist with you

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, still twitter link is not clickable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84367/discussion-between-user2526811-and-anbu-karthik).